# Permanently stop a YouTube autosuggestion for a single video during auto play?

Tags: youtube

After one song is played, YouTube plays another and another - this feature is called 'auto-play'.

Often, YouTube predicts what you will enjoy based on what others have enjoyed, but occasionally YouTube's recommendation is a bad one, yet it will keep recommending it.

How can I tell YouTube I never want to see a video again?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution, but what I did instead is simply [block the channel of that the video comes from](https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/stop-a-specific-video-in-youtube-autoplay.140269/)

Unfortunately, that means you won't see other videos from that channel.

To block a channel, visit the channel page -> About -> (click the flag icon) -> Block